# Installed Lubuntu alternate 32 bit ver 14.04.1 on old Lenovo S10 - no wireless

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, broadcom

I am completely new to lubuntu / ubuntu. I've installed "lubuntu 14.04.1 alternate" (CD version, as I could not get laptop to boot from usb) successfully on old Lenovo S10. It will network via ethernet cable, but does not find the wireless connection.

I've searched Ubuntu questions and found lots of people have the same issue with Broadcom wireless device.

have run the

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9
```

Network command and know that my

```
chip ID is BCM4312 
PCI-ID is 14e4:4315 
kernel driver is wl
```

Beyond this I am stuck.

Have tried to make sense of the various fixes other people have suggested, but either it does not work or I do not understand how to do what they suggest.

How can I get the wireless running?

Sorry, I need simple instructions please.

Answer (score 0):

Your wifi should be supported with the b43 module with the firmware, so

`sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-dkms`

`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` and reboot

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it does not seem to have worked.

Comment: I reinstalled lubuntu 14.04.1 (clean install), updated software when prompted, and also `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo update-pciids`. Then followed the advice of @Jeremy31 but still no Wi-Fi networks appear in the network manager, only wired connection via ethernet.

Comment: As per advice from @Luis Alvarado in his response to question [http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers], after installing the firmware-b43-installer you need to remove the b43 module, enable it again and even proceed to unblock with rfkill:

 `sudo modprobe -r b43`
 `sudo modprobe b43`    
 `sudo rfkill unblock all` but still it does not work.

Comment: Is wl still the driver or is b43?

Comment: How do I find that out?

Comment: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` should tell you about network drivers

Comment: BCM5906M fast ethernet PCI express 14e4:1713 (rev 02). Subsystem Lenovo ideapad S10e 17aa:3a23. kernel driver: tg3.

Comment: Networkcontroller: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY 14e4:4315 (rev 01). subsystem: broadcom device 14e4:04b5. Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

Comment: Strange, what kernel? `uname -a` as you might need `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer` or possibly download firmware-b43-lpphy-installer from an alternate source

Comment: Linux pc name 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:18 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Any error messages in `dmesg | grep b43`

Comment: three lines come up: broadcom 4312 WLAN found (core revision 15)

Comment: Found PHY: Analog 6, Type 5 (LP), Revision 1

Comment: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)